# Doctrine 2 with ZF2 how to update row

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am trying to update a row in an entity using:

```
$linker = $this->getObjectManager()->getRepository('\Schema\Entity\Link')->find('link_id', 7853);
           $linker->setSampleTitle($mytitle);
           $linker->setSampleDesc($mydesc);

           $this->getObjectManager()->merge($linker);
           $this->getObjectManager()->flush();
```

But i get: **An open transaction is required for this operation.**

Comment: Actually both of your `find()` approaches is correct. However the first one "queries the table", the second one "queries the database" - so to speak... As pointed out by @doeni you simply used the wrong function to save your updated entity. It's `persist()` what you're looking for instead of `merge()`

Comment: Hi, the truth is that I completly removed $this->getObjectManager()->merge($linker); and using the method I posted below it worked without using neither `persist` nor `merge`. I only used `merge`beacause i read it in another post without knowing what exactly does. Is it required to use `persist()`?

Comment: Yeah i forget this myself, too. Updating only needs flushing... Persisting is not required as this is all handled internally in case of edit. flush() will write it to the DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized that inside the `find()` method i should not put `'link_id'` but the class `\Schema\Entity\Link`. So `getRepository()` is not needed here...

Correct is: `$linker= $this->getObjectManager()->find('\Schema\Entity\Link', 7853);`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$this->getObjectManager()->persist($linker);
$this->getObjectManager()->flush();
```

Also you might want to use findOneBy instead of find.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Link = $this->getObjectManager->getRepository('Schema\Entity\Link')->find( 7853 );
```

and define `link_id` as id in **Entity** by @id or use `findBy` keyword